# How to display splashcreen after an 'If' statement in eclipse?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am trying to develop a game in which a splash screen will appear after the player completes a stage. After displaying the splash screen, he will be directed to the next level. Can you give me any suggestions on how to do that? I have tried using `Intent` but it doesn't work. This is what the code looks like:

```
if (sprite.isCollision(x, y)) {
if (i < badsprite) {
score++;
badsprite--;
sounds.play(sndSquish, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0  , 0, 1.5f);
} else{
life--;
sounds.play(sndOuch, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0, 0, 1.5f);
}
sprites.remove(sprite);
temps.add(new PorchTempSprite(temps, this, x, y, bmpSlime));
if((sec != 0) && (badsprite == 0) && (life > 0)) {

    //this is where I want to display the splash 
   //this is where i want to insert the codes for Intent                     

                                }
                            break;
                          }
                   } 
            }
     }
  return true;
  } 
}
```

Thank you in advance....

Comment: indicate where you want to start the splash in your code with comment `//`

Comment: I have indicated it. @Elltz

Answer (score 0):

one easy way is to create a xml file and set the theme to **Theme.transculent**
and then use intent to an activity that holds this xml

Answer (score 0):

you can either replace the whole display area with your splash screen
eg if you have a `RelativeLayout` as your top most view of your game container give it an `id` and do this

```
if((sec != 0) && (badsprite == 0) && (life > 0)) {
//this is where I want to display the splash 
//this is where i want to insert the codes for Intent
(ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.id)).removeAllViews(); // removes the views
// you can also hide your toolbar here
(ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.id)).addView(//inflate your splash view or layout);
 // you can add params

}
```

in effect the user sees a splash screen.. then you wait and move on..
**W**ith intents if you call `startActivity(intent);` then you need to check in the `onpause()` whether you are to move to the next level, and use a `boolean` so in the `onresume()` of this same activity you move to the next level, and in your splash screen activity you wait for the duration you want an start your game activity with `startActivity(intent);` and add `finish()` to it.. you can always enforce a delay with `hanlder().postDelayed(runnable,duration)` //3000 is 3 seconds

hope i touched your question..